# Segmentation fault when passing double pointer and pointer to function

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

When I do:

```
t_node *node1;
t_node **head;
void *elem;
int c = 1;

elem = &c;
head = NULL;
node1 = malloc(sizeof(t_node));
node1->elem = elem;
head = &node1;
//add_node(node1,head); //substitute this with line above and it doesn't work
printf("%d\n",*(int*)(*head)->elem); // prints 1 and works fine
```

BUT WHEN I CREATE A FUNCTION CALLED ADD_NODE IT DOESN'T WORK?!??!?

```
void add_node(t_node *node1, t_node **head){
   head = &node1;
}
```

this doesn't make any sense to me... why would this cause this to not work? calling the function literally does the same exact code.

EDIT: Keep in mind the signature of the add_node is not under question. it is required of me to have that signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is a pass by value language.  Your function actually doesn't do anything at all as far as `main()` is concerned.

Check out [this question](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) in the comp.lang.c FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

In the call to the function the parameters have a scope that is only of that function, so your assignment of 'head = &node1' has no affect to variables outside the function.

To affect the variables you passed in, you must pass the address of the variables. Eg:

```
void add_node(t_node **node1, t_node ***head){
   *head = node1;
}
```

and the call would be:

```
add_node(&node1, &head);
```

Note that you must dereference the 'head' pointer in the function so the value at 'head' would be updated with the 'node1' value.

Answer (score 2):

in 'C' varaibles are passed by reference, so to change the value in function call you should pass the pointer to variable.

correct step would be -

void add_node(t_node **node1, t_node ***head){
   *head = node1;
}